# Query for child component with a specific xtype

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is there a method to query for a child component of xtype 'yourxtype' ?
For example you have a panel, and inside this panel is a custom xtype located on a toolbar.

The findParentByType works great for looking up, but there is not method like findChildByType.
And the down method works only on elements. The Ext.ComponentQuery is a singleton, but not for xtypes? 
Is there another way to query from a component down?

Answer (score 11):

`yourCt.down` will find the first instance of a container with the specified type, in the component's children and descendants.

`yourCt.child` will do the same, but restrict to the direct children of the container.

`yourCt.query` will find *all* of the matching components underneath the container, as an array.

`yourCt.up` will find the first *parent* of the container that matches.

Oh, and `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` can take an optional object that is used as the start point for the query.

These are all based off (and clearly documented in) [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With yourCT, you mean a component that is of a container type yes? Because when I double click on a gridpanel, then you have acces the the view of the gridpanel.
But from  there you don't have the option to query down. Do you know how to travel down from the grid view?

Comment: If it's not a container, then by definition it doesn't contain anything. (There are 'containers' besides Ext.container.Container, though - see the Queryable mixing for more detail) So, no. You need to go from the view back to the containing Grid and query from there.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your reply, I did what you said. I tried to go up with findParentByType('gridpanel') and it retuned the right gridpanel. From there I tried the .down('mycustomxtype') but it was null.  The custom xtype is located in a tbar {  xtype:'mycustomxtype }  I also tried the method dockedItems, but the array was empty. Really strange.. could it be a bug? In ext js 3.4 you had to use the getBottomToolbar method and there you could query for your xtype

Answer (score 4):

There is also a [`down`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-down) method for component queries, but it is only available for containers. And component queries looks in xtypes for identifiers with no prefix (eg. "#", ".", etc.), it has no importance if the xtype is defined by Ext or your self. So jut do:

```
var child = yourCt.down('yourxtype');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the component that I am in, is not a container. In my example it is of type Ext.grid.View  Does that mean it's not possible to query from there?

Comment: since queries are done by xtype can it happen that in some query I will refer to two different objects having same xtype? How are such conflicts resolved? Maybe you have some link where is discussion about this? (Because we may have class with some xtype but also we may have different instances of this class right?and using xtype for searching doesn't seem to differentiate instances?)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

This returns an array of instances with the mention xtype.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('fieldxtype')
```

This returns only single instance i.e if we have 5 instances of the xtype.it will return only first instance of the xtype

```
formpanel.down('fieldxtype')
```

if you want get an component by name you can use

```
 var componentArray = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=checkboxName]');

 var componentObj = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=checkboxName]')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply query using 
`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myXtype')` this will return an array of all instances of your type.